# How to access the index of the selected cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a few cells in my UICollectionView in which I create buttons:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height))
    button.setTitle("ButtonTitle")
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

Then I add a action to the button which switches to a new ViewController setting the name of the button as title with:

```
func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let vc = NewViewController()
    vc.title = sender!.titleLabel!!.text
    revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

But I now also would like to access the index of the selected cell / button. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: can you add some more code .. it is easy to resolve

Comment: yes i know.. =) actually i used a UIButton as senderObject and accessed it with sender.titleLabel?.text..but i was testing around and posted some of my trial code.. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entire cell is displaying a button maybe you should just remove the button and implement the following:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Perform any action you want after a cell is tapped
    // Access the selected cell's index with the indexPath.item value
    let item = itemCollection[indexPath.item]
    
}
```

Comment: this would be similar to tableViewCell..didn't thought of that actually.. will try this..

Comment: worked as well..think this is the prettiest way to do it..similiar to tableView's..thank you!

Comment: @manu could you suggest how did you solve that? I have a similar problem, have could of views in CollectionView and would like to pass different data based on the view I click

Comment: @lukas28277 You could use the `indexPath.item` to access a one-dimensional array, like this `let item = itemCollection[indexPath.item]`

Comment: @lukas28277 Exactly. Just use the method posted in the answer, with ```indexPath``` you have the reference to the cell which was clicked.

Answer (score 3):

do like

**Step-1**

```
 button.tag = indexPath.row
 button.setTitle("ButtonTitle")
 button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

**Step-2**

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    if let sendertitle = sender.titleLabel?.text {

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewViewControllerIdentifier") as? NewViewController
        vc.title = sendertitle

        revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Choice -- 2**

if you want to implemnt the simple way do like

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}
```

on didSelect call

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewViewControllerIdentifier") as? NewViewController
    vc.indexPath = indexPath.row

    revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
 }
```

Comment: `button.tag = indexPath.row` worked but I called with `vc.indexPath = sender?.tag`.. thank you!

Comment: accepted your answer but unfortunately cannot up vote it because i'm a small fish here in stack overflow..=)

Comment: @manu -- dont think like that , in your question and answer useful for future, one day you also shine surely in stack over flow, like Matt, martin, Rmmaddy, Eric, vadian, etc.., we are also cross on same way

Answer (score 2):

Just use this method :

```
let point = button.convertPoint(btn.bounds.origin, toView: self.collectionView)
let mypath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)
```

Use your button position to get the proper indexpath

Comment: problem that in the button action i cannot access the selected cell..but I'll try the solution Laffen posted..

Answer (score 2):

In your buttonAction:

```
    let btn = sender as! UIButton
    let point = btn.convertPoint(btn.bounds.origin, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
```